# Eclipse errors cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, iterator, linked-list

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;    

public class HW1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){    

        String s = "";
        boolean flag = false;
        int pos = -1;

        List roster = new LinkedList();   <--
        roster.add ( "alice" );
        roster.add ( "bob" );
        roster.add ( "chad" );
        roster.add ( "dan" );
        ListIterator<String> bookmark = roster.listIterator(); <--

        try {
            s = bookmark.next();
            s = bookmark.next();
            s = bookmark.next();
            s = bookmark.next();
            s = bookmark.next();
            flag = bookmark.hasNext();
            pos = bookmark.nextIndex();
        }catch ( Exception trouble ) {
            s = "Runtime Error generated";
        }

    }
}
```

This is considered a homework question, however I'm not looking for an answer. I'm getting multiple errors about resolving to a type, at the first error I get LinkedList and List cannot be resolved to a type. At the second arrow I get ListIterator cannot be resolved to a type.

I am very new to Eclipse and we haven't done any code writing yet for this class so I am not used to the format Can anyone tell me how to resolve the errors I am getting

Updated* Same errors as before except I now have 3 more. List and LinkedList are a type mismatch, LinkedList is a raw type and references to a generic type need to be parameterized. then the second arrow I now get listIterator() is undefined for the type

Comment: `Control + Shift + O` Fix your imports. See if that helps.

Comment: I still have the cannot resolved to a type errors, however now I get 3 additional errors, at the first arrow I now get LinkedList is a raw type references should be parameterized, along with a type mismatch between list and LinkedList

Comment: Also after importing the libraries the code then instantly terminates

Comment: If you have compile errors, it should not be running to begin with...

Comment: Verify that your project points to a valid JRE in its Java Build Path.

Comment: Side note, `Control + Shift + F` in Eclipse beautifies your code :D

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
List roster = new LinkedList();
```

needs to become:

```
LinkedList roster = new LinkedList();
```

Comment: The original posted code imported java.awt.List instead of java.util.List.

Answer (score 2):

Have you imported the libraries at the beginning of your program?

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
```

Answer (score 1):

List is generic type, so you need to declare it as

```
List<String> myString = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
```

just this and creating object syntax is

```
Class_name obj_name = new Class_name();
```